# Scala bomb? (like a zip bomb)

Tags: scala, class, compiler-construction

Please excuse the funny title, I am using it in analogy with "[zip bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_bomb)". Is it possible to create a scala source file, that will, when compiled, produce a large number of class files (or a very large single class file)? Is there any way the size of the class files could grow faster than linearly with the size of the source file?

Comment: What in hell could you possibly need that for?

Comment: @NikitaVolkov It sounds like an interesting mental exercise, but I have a problem trying to find a practical application.

Comment: Ok, for those people who need pratical applications: Trying to protect a service that compiles Scala code from DOS attacks.

Comment: What a fun question!

Comment: @KimStebel: Don't forget that Scala's type system is Turing-complete, which means it is possible to write a program which will take an infinite amount of time to typecheck.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't really concerned with runtime though, since that will be limited anyway.

Comment: @Kim, this does't really answer the stated question, but your best bet to protect your service is to have some kind of watchdog that just kills the compiler after `x` seconds or `y` MB.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Specialization is inherently exponential in the number of type parameters specialized.

```
class Huge[@specialized A, @specialized B, @specialized C](
  val a: A, val b: B, val c: C
) {} // 730 files, 2.9 MB

class Gigantic[@specialized A, @specialized B, @specialized C, @specialized D](
  val a: A, val b: B, val c: C, val d: D
) {} // 6562 files, 26 MB
```

Pattern matching can also involve a lot of code duplication for complex cases (though I find it difficult to predict exactly when this will occur).

Comment: Ah, I've never used specialization, great answer!

Comment: Rex, for info, there is a bug raised for the pattern matching https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1133, it fails because too much code is generated. This should be fixed with the new virtual pattern matcher in 2.10 though.