# What @unspecialized annotation is for?

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

Reading a source code of Function2 [I've noticed that @unspecialized](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.2/src/library/scala/Function2.scala#L53) was [added recently (in scala 2.10)](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/3404d5a9bf750e7022934d6b70035718544be900). What is the reasoning behind it and how does it affect compilation? Why do we need it for Function*'s `tupled`, `compose` and some other methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that a safe guess is that it disables specialization for the target method. A good reason to disable specialization is to avoid bytecode bloat. Specializing every method indiscriminately is a bad idea, because each specialization is basically a distinct copy of the same method, and the bytecode size grows pretty fast. So I guess here that specializing `Function2` was deemed generally worth the increased bytecode size, at the exception of `tupled` and `compose` which were not important enough to warrant an additonal increase. It's a delicate balance between code size and execution speed, the idea is to get the most bangs for the bucks.

Aside: as a funny illustration of how problematic the code bloat induced by specilization can be, see this recipe for a *scala bomb* :

[Scala bomb? (like a zip bomb)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551435/scala-bomb-like-a-zip-bomb)