# Java source bomb (like zip bomb)

Tags: java

I found question about [Scala bomb (like a zip bomb)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551435/scala-bomb-like-a-zip-bomb)

And I'm interested the same question but about `java`:

> Is it possible to create a java source file, that will, when compiled,
>   produce a large number of class files (or a very large single class
>   file)? Is there any way the size of the class files could grow faster
>   than linearly with the size of the source file?

Answer (score 1):

There are some tricks. But there is no recipe to create *the best* bomb. You would probably need to run challenges to find some good entries.

---

There was a similar one at *codegolf.se*: [Build a Compiler Bomb](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69189/build-a-compiler-bomb/69376#69376)

And user @Sleafar shows a Java variant: [Java, 450 + 22 = 472 bytes source, ~1GB class file](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/69376)

Here is a copy of his code:

```
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor;
import javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedAnnotationTypes;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedSourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.SourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement;

@SupportedAnnotationTypes("java.lang.Override")
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_8)
public class B extends AbstractProcessor {
    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations,
            RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        if (annotations.size() > 0) {
            try (Writer writer = processingEnv.getFiler().createSourceFile("C")
                    .openWriter()) {
                writer.write("class C{int ");
                for (int i = 0; i < 16380; ++i) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 65500; ++j) {
                        writer.write("i");
                    }
                    writer.write(i + ";int ");
                }
                writer.write("i;}");
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

As explained there, it uses Annotation Processors and needs two compile passes:

```
javac B.java
javac -J-Xmx16G -processor B B.java
```

The resulting class file is then about `1 GB` big.

---

This answer is **community wiki** as it only shows a copy of another ones answer from a different site. Close vote is not appropriate since there was no similar question at SO and it's still on-topic.